# TypeScript Date Format options similar to those in .NET?

Tags: c#, typescript

In C# .NET I can easily change the Format of a date like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
string date1 = date.ToString("dd MMM yy");
string date2 = date.ToString("yyyy/MM");
string date3 = date.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
```

and so on...

How can I achieve something similar in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching the internet I found this [JavaScript file](https://gist.github.com/marlun78/1351171) on GitHub written by marlun78.

As I want to help others working with TypeScript I decided to post here my solution. So what I did is rewrite the code in TypeScript. Here it is:

```
export interface IFormatDateSettings {
days?: string[];
daysAbbr?: string[];
designators?: string[];
defaultFormat?: string;
months?: string[];
monthsAbbr?: string[];
os?: string[];
}

/**
* Date Format
* Copyright (c) 2011, marlun78
* MIT License, https://gist.github.com/marlun78/bd0800cf5e8053ba9f83
*
* Format options inspired by the .NET framework's format.
* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
*
* Non-formatting characters within the format string must be
* quoted (single (') or double (") quotes)! The same is true
* for two format specifiers that should apear together. Eg.
* if you want the date to be output with the date ordinal
* (9th), the format string must be "d''x" (or 'd""x').
*
* Arguments:
*     format   {String} The format pattern to display the date in. See Format Patterns section below for options.
*     settings {Object} Formatting settings.
*
* Settings:
*     asUtc      {Boolean} If the formatted date is to be returned as a UTC date.
*     days       {Array}   The days of the week. Starting with Sunday.
*     daysAbbr   {Array}   The days of the week, abbreviated. Starting with Sunday.
*     designator {Array}   Time designator. Starting with AM.
*     format     {String}  The format pattern to format the date in.
*     months     {Array}   The name of the months. Starting with January.
*     monthsAbbr {Array}   The name of the months, abbreviated. Starting with January.
*
* Format Patterns:
*      d       1-31                The day of the month
*      dd      01-31               The day of the month
*      ddd     Mon-Sun             The abbreviated name of the day of the week
*      dddd    Monday-Sunday       The full name of the day of the week
*      f       6                   The tenths of a second in a date and time value. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      ff      61                  The hundredths of a second in a date and time value. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      fff     617                 The milliseconds in a date and time value. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      ffff    6170                The milliseconds in a date and time value, with a trailing zero. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      fffff   61700               The milliseconds in a date and time value, with two trailing zeros. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      ffffff  617000              The milliseconds in a date and time value, with three trailing zeros. The remaining digits are truncated.
*      F       6                   The tenths of a second in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      FF      61                  The hundredths of a second in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      FFF     617                 The milliseconds in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      FFFF    617                 The milliseconds in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      FFFFF   617                 The milliseconds in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      FFFFFF  617                 The milliseconds in a date and time value. Trailing zeros or zero values are not displayed.
*      h       1-12                The hour, using a 12-hour clock
*      hh      01-12               The hour, using a 12-hour clock
*      H       0-23                The hour, using a 24-hour clock
*      HH      00-23               The hour, using a 24-hour clock
*      m       0-59                The minute
*      mm      00-59               The minute
*      M       1-12                The month
*      MM      01-12               The month
*      MMM     Jan-Dec             The abbreviated name of the month
*      MMMM    January-December    The full name of the month
*      s       0-59                The second
*      ss      00-59               The second
*      tt      AM/PM               The AM/PM designator
*      x       st, nd, rd, th      The ordinal suffix of a number (NOTE! This does not exist in .NET!)
*      y       0-99                The year
*      yy      00-99               The year
*      yyy     001-9999            The year, with a minimum of three digits
*      yyyy    0001-9999           The year as a four-digit number
*      z       +1                  Hours offset from UTC, with no leading zeros.
*      zz      +01                 Hours offset from UTC, with a leading zero for a single-digit value.
*      zzz     +01:00              Hours and minutes offset from UTC.
*
* Example:
*     The formatting method can be called in the following three ways:
*     formatDate(format, settings) {String} The format string passed is used, any settings are stored.
*                                           If the settings object contain a format property, it will override the format string.
*     formatDate(settings)         {String} Settings are stored and the stored format is used.
*     formatDate()                 {String} Default settings are used.
*/
export class FormatDateService {

static settings: IFormatDateSettings = {
    days: 'Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday'.split(' '),
    daysAbbr: 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' '),
    designators: 'AM PM'.split(' '),
    defaultFormat: 'MMMM d""x "at" h:mm tt',
    months: 'January February March April May June July August September October November December'.split(' '),
    monthsAbbr: 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' '),
    os: 'th st nd rd th'.split(' ')
};

asUtc: boolean = false;

handlers = {
    d: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return date[this.getMethod('Date')](); },
    dd: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Date')]()); },
    ddd: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getDayName(date, true, settings); },
    dddd: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getDayName(date, undefined, settings); },
    f: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 1);
    },
    ff: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 2);
    },
    fff: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 3);
    },
    ffff: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 4);
    },
    fffff: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 5);
    },
    ffffff: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        return this.pad(this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3), 6, true).substr(0, 6);
    },
    F: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let r = this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3).substr(0, 1); return r === '0' ? '' : r;
    },
    FF: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let r = this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3).substr(0, 2); return r === '00' ? '' : r;
    },
    FFF: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Milliseconds')](), 3).substr(0, 3); },
    FFFF: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.handlers.FFF(date, settings); },
    FFFFF: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.handlers.FFF(date, settings); },
    FFFFFF: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.handlers.FFF(date, settings); },
    h: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { let h = date[this.getMethod('Hours')](); return h > 12 ? h - 12 : h; },
    hh: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { let h = date[this.getMethod('Hours')](); return this.pad(h > 12 ? h - 12 : h); },
    m: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return date[this.getMethod('Minutes')](); },
    mm: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Minutes')]()); },
    H: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return date[this.getMethod('Hours')](); },
    HH: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Hours')]()); },
    M: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return date[this.getMethod('Month')]() + 1; },
    MM: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Month')]() + 1); },
    MMM: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getMonthName(date, true, settings); },
    MMMM: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getMonthName(date, undefined, settings); },
    s: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return date[this.getMethod('Seconds')](); },
    ss: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('Seconds')]()); },
    tt: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getDesignator(date, settings); },
    x: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.getOrdinal(date, settings); },
    y: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let y = date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), s = y.toString(); return y < 10 ? y : s.substr(s.length - 2);
    },
    yy: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), 2); },
    yyy: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let y = date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), s = y.toString(); return y < 1000 ? this.pad(y, 3) : s.substr(s.length - 4);
    },
    yyyy: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), 4); },
    yyyyy: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), 5); },
    yyyyyy: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { return this.pad(date[this.getMethod('FullYear')](), 6); },
    z: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => { let t = date.getTimezoneOffset(); return (t > 0 ? '-' : '+') + Math.abs(t / 60); },
    zz: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let t = date.getTimezoneOffset(); return (t > 0 ? '-' : '+') + this.pad(Math.abs(t / 60));
    },
    zzz: (date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings) => {
        let t = date.getTimezoneOffset(); return (t > 0 ? '-' : '+') +
            this.pad(Math.abs(t / 60)) + ':' + this.pad((Math.abs(t / 60) % 1) * 60);
    }
};

findPatterns: RegExp = /([dfFhmHMstxyz]+)(?=([^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)/g;

getMethod(method: string): string {
    return 'get' + (this.asUtc ? 'UTC' : '') + method;
};

public formatDate(date: Date, format: string = undefined, settings: IFormatDateSettings = undefined): string {
    let usedSettings: IFormatDateSettings = FormatDateService.settings;

    if (settings) {
        usedSettings = Object.assign({}, FormatDateService.settings, settings);
    }

    if (!format) {
        format = usedSettings.defaultFormat;
    }

    return format.replace(this.findPatterns, (match, group1) => {
        let fn = this.handlers[group1];
        return typeof fn === 'function' ? fn(date, usedSettings) : match;
    }).replace(/["']/g, '');
};


getDayName(date: Date, asAbbr: boolean, settings: IFormatDateSettings): string {
    let n: number = date.getDay();
    return asAbbr ? settings.daysAbbr[n] : settings.days[n];
};

getMonthName(date: Date, asAbbr: boolean, settings: IFormatDateSettings): string {
    let n: number = date.getMonth();
    return asAbbr ? settings.monthsAbbr[n] : settings.months[n];
};


getOrdinal(date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings): string {
    let d: number = date.getDate();
    return (d > 3 && d < 21) ? settings.os[0] : settings.os[Math.min(d % 10, 4)];
}

getDesignator(date: Date, settings: IFormatDateSettings): string {
    return date.getHours() >= 12 ? settings.designators[1] : settings.designators[0];
};

pad(obj: any, len: any = undefined, fromRight: any = undefined): string {
    let p = '000000';
    return fromRight ?
        (obj + p).slice(0, len ? Math.min(len, p.length) : 2) :
        (p + obj).slice(-(len ? Math.min(len, p.length) : 2));
}
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let date:Date = new Date(); 
let formatdateService = new FormatDateService();
let formatedDate1:string = formatdateService.formatDate(date, 'dd MM yy');
let formatedDate2:string = formatdateService.formatDate(date, 'yyyy/MM'); 
let formatedDate3:string = formatdateService.formatDate(date, 'MMMM d, yyyy');
```